# Why this error when executing MongoDB on Cygwin?

Tags: mongodb, cygwin

I copied the `MongoDB` executables<sup>1</sup> to my Cygwin's `/usr/local/bin` directory.

However, when I try to execute, I get this opaque error message:

```
$ mongod
C:/cygwin/usr/local/bin/mongod.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

### Do you know which is the culprit DLL hiding behind that error's question mark?

<sup>1</sup> Files from the `bin/` directory on `https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/x86_64-2008plus/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-v3.0-latest.zip`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Windows `PATH` variable to include `C:\cygwin64\bin`

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\cygwin64\bin
```

Comment: I did add the directories to bash's $PATH. However, to test your suggestion, I also added the directories to Windows %PATH% (and rebooted). Alas, the problem is still the same.